# How to keep a device at a fixed Comport when removing and inserting

Tags: serial-port

No serial I/O isn't dead :) The example I am going to use is a GPS device on a Windows computer. When you put a GPS locator on a computer it, as a rule, comes in to Device Manager as a COM Port. All communication to and from that device is done via serial I/O.

The issue comes when you unplug the device (pull the USB cable out) and plug it back in. There is no guarantee that the device will come back in to the computer at the same COM Port. That can be problematic.

Does anyone know of a way to guarantee that it will come back to the exact same COM Port every time?

Comment: Often this functionality is dependent on the drivers for the device in question. Usually plugging the device back in to the same USB port *should* result in the same COM port.

Comment: I don't believe drivers are at all responsible for what COM Port the device comes in as are they? From what I understand all devices of this type are "Virtual Com Ports" and just tell Windows "You Decide" and Windows simply assigns the first available COM Port. They do give you the ability to change the COM Port of the device but what I have found is that even then it won't survive a unpluf/replug.

Comment: *There is no guarantee that the device will come back in to the computer at the same COM Port.* 1) You must plug the device into the same USB port (physically) 2) If some another device which uses COM-port emulation is used between un-plug and re-plug (either physical or logical) then your COM-port may be altered - I recommend you plug your device, then select it in Device manager and change its COM-port number to some number which is greater then current (close to the maximal value in list).

Comment: You are correct on why it is moving hence the question. I can't rely on the end users to jump through hoops like that. I need a way registry or otherwise to automatically have it come back to the same Comport every tme.

Comment: Some suggestions here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13741853/how-to-get-stable-com-ports-for-usb-serial-dongles-in-windows-xp